# RIDE-1.5.2.1 can not import all the base Libraries

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I uptate the RIDE-1.5.2.1 to RIDE-1.7.3 ,I found that RIDE do not work well. I uninstall the wxpython,robotframework,RIDE and full install them. But then I could not import the library. I get this error Log:

> 20190319 12:21:13.079 [INFO]: Found Robot Framework version 3.0.4 from
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot'.
>
> 20190319 12:21:13.079 [INFO]: Started RIDE 1.5.2.1 using python
>   version 2.7.14 with wx version 2.8.12.1 in win32.
>
> 20190319 12:22:49.749 [WARN]: Library import handling threw an
>   unexpected exception
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): table libraries has 5 columns but 4
>   values were supplied   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line
>   40, in run
>       if not self._handle_message():   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line
>   66, in _handle_message
>       self._handle_insert_keywords_message(message)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line
>   95, in _handle_insert_keywords_message
>       lambda res: result_queue.put(res, timeout=3))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarymanager.py", line
>   99, in _insert
>       library_name, library_args, keywords or [])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarydatabase.py", line
>   84, in insert_library_keywords
>       lib = self._insert_library(library_name, library_arguments, cur)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\spec\librarydatabase.py",
>   line 111, in _insert_library
>       cursor.execute('insert into libraries values (null, ?, ?, ?)', (name, unicode(arguments), time.time()))
>
> 20190319 12:22:51.559 [INFO]: Failed to read keywords from library db:

and here the library:

[image]

any tips to solve this problem and thanks

Comment: 1- Full uninstallation of python and related libraries
2- Delete Remaining Files and Folders of the Program, to delete these leftovers, you'll need check following folders:

%programfiles%
%programfiles(x86)%
%appdata%

3- Remove Software Keys from Windows Registry. Type regedit in RUN or Start Menu search box

KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software

4- Empty Temp Folder: %temp%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were changes in the database for keywords documentation storage in 1.7.3.
To clean up that database you have to delete the `librarykeywords.db` file in the `%APPDATA%\RobotFramework\ride` directory. Then start RIDE and it will be recreated whenever you open a test suite (it may take some time until the red color changes to black on the Library imports).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already solved this problem as you mentioned.